# c# linq xml how to use two prefixes for same namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, namespaces, prefix

Is there a way in Linq to use two prefixes for the same namespace? Example, I have two prefixes below "foo1" and "foo2" pointing to the same namespace that I want to use in my document. How do I do that?

```
<foo1:Begin foo2:Name="somevalue" xmlns:foo1="http://foo" xmlns:foo2="http://foo" xmlns="http://bar">
    <foo1:Child foo2:Name="somename" />
    <SomeBarElement />
</foo1:Begin>
```

In all my code I define the elements as:

```
string foo = "http://foo";
string bar = "http://bar";

string foo1 = "foo1";
string foo2 = "foo2";

XName Begin = "{" + foo + "}" + "Begin";
XName Child = "{" + foo + "}" + "Child";
XName Name = "{" + foo + "}"  + "Name";
XName SomeBarElement = "{" + bar + "}"  + "SomeBarElement";
```

I would like to be able to use a similar definition and usuage of elements to maintain consistency. And wherever I dont have two prefixes I do something like:

```
XElement doc = new XElement(Begin,
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + foo1, foo),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns, bar),
        new XElement(Child, new XAttribute(Name, "somename")),
        new XElement(SomeBarElement)
    );
```

I need two prefixes since the namespaces may change later - and even if not, it makes sense to logically separate the elements using different prefixes.

Comment: and why do you have such requirement... ?

Comment: I need two prefixes since it makes sense to logically separate the elements in the same namespace. Nevertheless, since this is technically valid xml, linq must allow some way of doing so, no?

Comment: Why do you need the namespaces to be the same today?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use two prefixes for the same namespace. You'd do this by using two namespaces with the same value.

```
var bar = XNamespace.Get("http://bar"); 
var foo1 = XNamespace.Get("http://foo");
var foo2 = XNamespace.Get("http://foo");

var x = new XElement(foo1 + "begin", 
    new XAttribute(foo2 + "Name", "somevalue"),
    new XElement("child", new XAttribute(foo2 + "Name", "somevalue")), 
    new XElement(bar + "barElement"));
```

**But** you cannot control XML namespace prefixes using LINQ-to-XML; and you should not *need* to control namespace prefixes.

This XML renders as

```
<begin p1:Name="somevalue" xmlns:p1="http://foo" xmlns="http://foo">
  <child p1:Name="somevalue" xmlns="" />
  <barElement xmlns="http://bar" />
</begin>
```

As you can see, you have three namespaces and both `xmlns` and `xmlns:p1` refer to your `http://foo` URI. But there's no way to tell LINQ-to-XML that it should use prefixes like `foo1`, `foo2` etc.

Trying to fiddle with XML namespace prefixes is unecessary hacking. Your code should not depend on concrete prefxies - they should be determined at parse time by reading the XML document itself.